# My Object isn't being called in my main function

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to call my object via the main function. Since it needs static reference , but I somehow can't get to do it. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
private double checking;
private double saving;


    public BankDisplay(double checking,double saving) // Constructor for subclass
    {
    checking=1000;
    saving=1000;

    }


    public void setChecking(double checking){
        this.checking=checking;
    }

    public double getChecking(){
        return checking;

    }

    public void setSaving(double saving){
        this.saving= saving;
    }

    public double getSaving(){
        return saving;

    }

BankDisplay checking1=new BankDisplay(checking, saving);
BankDisplay savings1= new BankDisplay(checking,saving);
```

When I am trying to print the object checking1 and saving1 in main it is showing "cant have a non static reference for a static function".

Comment: Objects can't be called. Only methods can be called.

Comment: In the `public static void main(String[] args)` method, create an instance of `BankDisplay` and use the methods accordingly.

Comment: So to print my checking value do I need to define the method in System.out.println("Checking"+"$"+checking1.getChecking());??

Comment: I want to print the value of the variable checking and saving? How do I do that??

Comment: Can you show us your whole program ?

Answer (score 1):

```
     public BankDisplay(double checking,double saving) // Constructor for subclass
        {
        this.checking=checking;
        this.saving=saving;

        }

There is an error in constructor.


public static void main(String[] args){
   BankingDisplay d1 = new BankingDisplay(100.15,200.15);
   System.out.println(d1.getChecking());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor's method is wrong, it should be:

```
public BankDisplay(double checking,double saving) // Constructor for subclass
    {
        this.checking = checking;
        this.saving = saving;
    }
```

You also should have a `toString()` function in your class for you to appropriately print objects.

Such as:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Checking: %s\nSavings: %s\n", this.checking, this.saving);
}
```

Use like this:

```
System.out.println(checking1.toString());
```

Comment: It would be better to override `toString` method and let the client consume it. Do not rely on `System.out.println` in your base code.

Comment: I just edited that, I'm so bad with typos. I guess I need to learn to type without an IDE holding my hand :P

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BankDisplay {
    private double checking;
    private double saving;

    public BankDisplay(double checking,double saving) // Constructor for subclass
    {
        this.checking= checking;
        this.saving= saving;
    }

    public void setChecking(double checking){
        this.checking=checking;
    }

    public double getChecking(){
        return checking;

    }

    public void setSaving(double saving){
        this.saving= saving;
    }

    public double getSaving(){
        return saving;

    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        BankDisplay account1 = new BankDisplay(1000,100);
        System.out.println(account1.getChecking());
    }
}
```

This should fix your issue :D you needed `this` in your constructor because you were setting the constructors values, not your private variables.

Comment: Not using this in the constructor doesn't cause any error message, even if the parameter has the same name as the object's property.

Comment: Yes it did fix it :D thank you so much. I think I know what to do now with the rest of the coding :) Thanks a ton